# One Page Sticky Navigation not working on Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, cross-browser, sticky

I am facing an odd problem with my sticky navigation on Google Chrome! Take a look at [this site](http://themebite.github.io/demo/effacy/)  using Firefox first then use Chrome. See the deference on the sticky menu

It works perfect on Mozilla Firefox. But when i visit the site using Google Chrome the Sticky menu start to crap! I don't know why this is happening. Can anyone give me a solution??

Here is a screenshot of the problem on Chrome[image: Sticky Menu Problem On Chrome]

And here is the [Live URL](http://themebite.github.io/demo/effacy/):

Comment: z-index:20 to "header-area"

Comment: Thanks it works now! :)

Comment: I also recommend editing your title to 'Fixed' instead of 'Sticky'

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.is-sticky {
    z-index: 99999;
    position: fixed;
}
```

This will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

**ISSUE SOLVED**

The problem was with my Navigation area. I gave the `z-index: 9999` on my nav element, But i had to give it to the Header-Area DIV.